# salt-ssh Do changes which spans several hosts

Tags: saltstack

I need to change two hosts:

- A new web-server gets configured
- A tunnel between tunnel-host and the new web-server should get created

We implemented both, and both steps work:

```
root@s# salt-ssh webserver-new state.sls webserver
root@s# salt-ssh tunnel-host state.sls tunnel
```

How to do this with salt-ssh?

Hosts of above example:

- s: the "master". It is not a salt-master, since we only use salt-ssh
- webserver-new: This host was configured for the first time with salt
- tunnel-host: This host creates some network tunnels which are needed for the new webserver.

Comment: Please elaborate instead of down-voting: What's wrong with this question?

Comment: Likely because there's not really a problem you're asking for answers regarding, but rather you're asking how to use salt-ssh with little to no information as to what issues you actually may be running into. If you have a specific issue, please post details on that so people can contribute to solve a problem; otherwise, you're attempting to invoke a meatware man page.

Comment: Which one is the master and which ones are the minions? Did you fill out the **roster**?

Comment: @Leo I added a list of all involved hosts.

Comment: @Spooler yes, you are right there is no specific issue. This is a general question about the way how to use salt-ssh if you want to change several hosts.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a [top file](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/top.html):

```
base:
  'webserver-new':
    - webserver
  'tunnel-host':
    - tunnel
```

and execute highstate on all hosts:

```
salt-ssh '*' state.apply
```

---

More advanced alternative would be to use [orchestration](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/orchestrate/orchestrate_runner.html) with [`ssh=true`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/ref/states/all/salt.states.saltmod.html) option, especially when states on different hosts depend on each other, but it requires a Salt master (even for salt-ssh minions).

```
# /srv/salt/orch/webserver.sls
setup_webserver:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: 'webserver-new'
    - ssh: true
    - sls:
      - webserver
create_tunnel:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: 'tunnel-host'
    - ssh: true
    - sls:
      - tunnel
    - require:
      - salt: setup_webserver
```

And execute it with `salt-run state.orchestrate orch.webserver`